# adding bed raw html form to room raw html as a pop up to add a lot of beds

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a raw html which i get the room details in which i need to add in a button pop up for a raw html form that can show up 
○ You should be able to add multiple beds for a Room
           § Each Bed entity will have following fields:
               □ Width
               □ Length
               □ Quantity
               □ Mattress Type
                   ® None
                   ® Innerspring
                   ® Pillow top
                   ® Hybrid
                   ® Specialty foam
                   ® Gel
                   ® Memory foam
                   ® Latex
                   ® Matress airbed
Matress waterbed

with each click on the +add beds it should show up the html form to add in details and then save all this while saving the Room form.

didnt find a better way to approach

NA

it must be a raw html with some js or jquery to pop up a html form on click fill in the details and when clicked on add bed it should open another html form and need to add in details and same must show in edit view too.must be able to remove the beds html form if not needed and in the end must save with the room html form.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so for that you definatelly need Javascript, or jQuery. On your button add event listener on click. In your html prepare form witch display attribute is set to None. If user clicks to button, this attribute is set to Block. If you want to do things asynchronously think about AJAX calls using jQuery. Let me know if that helped a bit ;)

Comment: that gave me a little idea about it